# How do I start an EWL project?

Tags: enterprise-web-library

Is there a process or solution template to create a brand new EWL project?

Comment: I just completed a major update to the page linked from my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official process:
https://enduracode.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W23